# Using react-native Navigator with redux for stateful routing and non-stateful

Tags: react-native, redux, navigator

So i started supporting redux application state in Navigator which is great. This gives you the flexibility to change a state based on an action ex: getSessionToken token doesn't exist change state to start walkthrough if token is invalid take them to loginState. However this becomes a problem when you want pages that aren't stateful or dependent on actions on redux. An example of this would be on the login page you have a link to the register page and use this.props.navigator.push() with the code posted below this would work but the problem lies when you use this.props.navigator.push and then try to have a stateful action happen. `route.component` seems to persist and never gets discarded.. This means the stateful routes can never be hit since route.component still holds a value. I was wondering if anyone has came up with a solution for this? Or has any ideas on how to make this code better.

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react-native'
let {Navigator,View} = React

import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux/native';
import {Map} from 'immutable';

/**
* Components
**/
import LoginContainer from './LoginContainer'
import MatchContainer from './MatchContainer'
import WalkthroughContainer from './WalkthroughContainer'

/**
* Actions
**/
import * as authActions from '../reducers/auth/authActions';
import * as globalActions from '../reducers/global/globalActions';
const actions = [authActions, globalActions]

// Save that state
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    ...state
  };
};

/**
* Bind all the functions from `actions` and bind them with `dispatch`
**/
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const creators = Map()
    .merge(...actions)
    .filter(value => typeof value === 'function')
    .toObject();

  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(creators, dispatch),
    dispatch
  };
}

/**
* App Class
**/
let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navigator: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

let App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      currentRoute: null,
    }
  },

  /**
  * change the route to match the current redux state
  **/
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({
      currentRoute: props.auth.form.state
    });
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getSessionToken();
  },

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    // This part is buggy
    if (route && route.component) {
      let Component = route.component;
      return (
        <Component navigator={navigator} />
      )
    }

    switch (this.state.currentRoute) {
      case 'LOGIN_STATE_LOGOUT':
        return <MatchContainer navigator={navigator} />
      case 'LOGIN_STATE_LOGIN':
        return <LoginContainer navigator={navigator} />
      case 'LOGIN_STATE_REGISTER':
        return <RegisterContainer navigator={navigator} />
      case 'WALKTHROUGH_STATE_START':
        return <WalkthroughContainer navigator={navigator} />
      default:
        return <View />
    }
  },

  render() {

    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.navigator}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        initialRoute={{ route: this.state.currentRoute }}
        configureScene={(route) => {
          if (route.sceneConfig) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
          }

          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid;
        }} />
    )

  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```